# Что лучше использовать в C# при сравнении на null "is" или "=="?

Tags: c#

Собственное сам вопрос:
Что лучше использовать при сравнении объекта на null "is" или "==" и в чем разница если она вообще есть?

```
if(item is null)
    throw new NullReferenceException(item);
```

или

```
if(item == null)
    throw new NullReferenceException(item);
```

Comment: [Pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#constant-pattern) - ссылка на документацию, с подтверждением того, что сказано в ответе Kalmankantaja.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Единственное, когда может быть разница - это когда `==` переопределён. А без переопределения оба варианта компилируется в один и тот же IL код и соответственно в один и тот же ассемблерный код, следовательно разницы между ними нет